# Get action name from within controller.php in the components

Tags: yii

Is there a way to get the current action name from within the Controller.php init function ?

Thanks

Comment: print_r(Yii::app()->controller); in init() will give you everything available

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, you can call `$this->action->id` within descendant of the `CController` class. 
Or you can use `Yii::app()->controller->action->id` through whole application.

But the method `init()` was called before the controller started to execute  (see http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#init-detail)

As you can see here: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWebApplication#runController-detail `actionID` will be passed to method `run()` only after `init()`:

```
$controller->init();
$controller->run($actionID);
```

Answer (score 0):

As **v2p** said, after init() run, we can get the controller id by Yii::app()->controller,also behavior id by Yii::app()->controller->action->id;Another way: Yii::app()->getController()->getAction()->id;